# 3rd size Avatar in Buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress, avatar

The below is in the bp-core-avatars.php file (Line:  375).

/**
* Look for uploaded avatar first. Use it if it exists.
* Set the file names to search for, to select the full size
* or thumbnail image.
*/

```
$avatar_size = ( ‘full’ == $type ) ? ‘-bpfull’ : ‘-bpthumb’;
$legacy_user_avatar_name = ( ‘full’ == $type ) ? ‘-avatar2′ : ‘-avatar1′;
$legacy_group_avatar_name = ( ‘full’ == $type ) ? ‘-groupavatar-full’ : ‘-groupavatar-thumb’;
```

On the line where it says $avatar_size, I need a third option called ’-bptinythumb’ size. Basically a choice between ‘-bpfull’, ‘-bpthumb’ and ’-bptinythumb’.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You’d change `$avatar_size = ( ‘full’ == $type ) ? ‘-bpfull’ : ‘-bpthumb;` to:

```
if ($type == 'full' ) {
    $avatar_size = '-bpfull';
} elseif ($type == 'thumb' ) {
    $avatar_size = '-bpthumb';
} else {
    $avatar_size = '-bptinythumb';
}
```

But that approach wouldn’t be recommended because when you upgrade BuddyPress your changes will be lost.

The tiny thumb will be the default avatar size. If you wanted to use the thumb or full versions then you’d need to pass `thumb` or `full` to `bp_core_fetch_avatar`